# execCommand('copy') fails on Chrome on OS X

Tags: javascript, html, macos, ecmascript-6, execcommand

Consider the following [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z3Lwppt9/) where the user can click on a div containing bold text and then do a copy (ctrl+c win cmd+c mac) to copy the html to the clipboard as HTML. If you then paste into for example a gmail you get the html formatting.

Basically the 'copyHtmlToClipboard' function creates a hidden div, copy the html to it, selects it with document.createRange and then calls document.execCommand('copy')

```
function copyHtmlToClipboard(html) {
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.style.opacity = 0;
  div.style.position = "absolute";
  div.style.pointerEvents = "none";
  div.style.zIndex = -1;  
  div.setAttribute('tabindex', '-1'); // so it can be focused
  div.innerHTML = html;
  document.body.appendChild(div);

  var focused=document.activeElement;
  div.focus();

  window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();  
  var range = document.createRange(); 
  // not using range.selectNode(div) as that makes chrome add an extra <br>
  range.setStartBefore(div.firstChild);
  range.setEndAfter(div.lastChild);
  //range.selectNode(div); 
  window.getSelection().addRange(range);  

  var ok=false;
  try {
    ok = document.execCommand('copy');
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  if (!ok) console.log('execCommand failed!');

  window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();  
  document.body.removeChild(div);

  focused.focus();
}
```

On windows Chrome/Firefox this works fine.

However on Mac Chrome execCommand returns false.

How can I make this code work on Mac ?

Thx!

Comment: https://clipboardjs.com/ - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell this is a chrome bug see:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=552975

Answer (score 1):

Safari doesn't have support for `copy` and `cut` commands.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: ok I see that. But what about Chrome on Mac ? why doesn't it work there and can it be made to work ?

Comment: I run [this](http://codepen.io/netsi1964/full/QbLLGW/) on both Mac and Windows and `copy` works on both Chromes Are you sure your version of Chrome is above version 42 on Mac?

Comment: but in the codepen it works ! what am I doing different ? can you try my fiddle pls ?

Comment: I will take a look once I have some time

Answer (score 1):

It happens because you are allowed to call `copy` command only after some events that caused by user actions.

These events are named "Semi-trusted events" and you can find the list [in spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-clipboard-apis-20140313/#semi-trusted-events). `copy` event is not in the list, so can't copy text in your event handler. You can listen to `keyup` event instead and then trigger your actions after check that `ctrl+c` was pressed

Comment: thx but this does not explain why it works on chrome windows but not on chrome mac

Comment: Maybe it is related with implementation of firing and hadnling `copy` event in these systems

Comment: reading the section you referenced, I don't think it is relevant. It is about dispatching copy event where as I am calling execCommand(copy) inside a copy event already dispatched by the browser

Comment: As far as I can tell the event _is trusted_ on chrome OSX. if I consolelog the isTrusted flag I get true. still execCommand('copy' returns false

Comment: I think the related bug is https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=552975